# How to provide a Renew option for DevDemon Subscriptions?

Tags: devdemon-subscriptions

I cannot find how to offer a Renew process. There is no documentation about a {exp:subs:renew} or similar tag. The tag exists as I can see it in the subs file system, and blank output occurs to the screen (as opposed to an error about not being able to process the tag).

Does anyone know how to offer a renewal process?

I would expect the renewal process to allow an active subscriber (with auto renew on or off), or a cancelled subscriber (that still have the plan left) to be able to make a payment which extends their subscription for the specified period of time.

At the moment a user can re-subscribe, but that just adds the same plan they are on with expiry set from the time they subscribe again, and it does not add the duration onto their already existing plan.

Thanks!